# SQL IS NOT NULL as a value in a CASE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case

I have a scenario where I want to choose non null values if B is equal to 61, I can't seem to find the correct syntax for this.

```
A          |        B
value1     |        61
value2     |        0 
NULL       |        61


WHERE A = CASE 
    WHEN B = 61
        THEN IS NOT NULL
    END
```

I want to select only the row with A=value1

Comment: Non null values from where?

Comment: The values can be from 0-71 but can be NULL as well

Comment: Your question is not clear. It would be helpful, if you provided sample data and desired result.

Comment: Wont this help ..`(B=61 AND A IS NOT NULL) OR B=XX` ?

Comment: Yes I think that will work thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many situations it isn't necessary to use case expressions or IF() in a where clause, conventionally it is handled by combining conditions in parentheses.

```
WHERE ( B = 61 AND A IS NOT NULL )
```

Here both conditions must be true for the combined condition to be true

Answer (score 1):

why not go straight forward ?

```
WHERE (B=61) AND (A IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have this like:

```
//thats really straight forward:
WHERE (A IS NOT NULL AND B=61)
```

or their is another way of picking you nose :)

```
WHERE
IF(A IS NOT NULL AND B=61,1,0) //add other conditions as you like
```